# Batch file: Variable within a variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a complex string I'm trying to parse. I have a short subroutine to fine the index of two specific characters, and I need the string in between. So the question is:
How do I use variables inside string manipulation of another variable?

Here's some sample code:

```
@ECHO off

set start=2
set end=5
set str=Hello World

echo %str:~2,5%
echo %str:~%start%,%end%%
```

How do I get the second echo to display what the first echo displays? (right now second echo is just showing what I want, it'll crash as is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO off

set start=2
set end=5
set str=Hello World

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo %str:~2,5%
echo !str:~%start%,%end%!
endlocal
```

or (the worst way)

```
@ECHO off

set start=2
set end=5
set str=Hello World

echo %str:~2,5%
call echo %%str:~%start%,%end%%%
```

or (can be used if start and end definition and the substringing are all  in brackets context)

```
@ECHO off

set start=2
set end=5
set str=Hello World

echo %str:~2,5%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%start% %end%") do echo !str:~%%a,%%b!
endlocal
```

or (also a bad way)

```
@ECHO off

set start=2
set end=5
set str=Hello World

call :substr "%str%" %start% %end%
goto :eof

:substr
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "_str=%~1"
echo !_str:~%2,%3!
rem without delayedExpansion
rem call echo %%_str:~%2,%3%%
endlocal
goto :eof
```

Comment: Rats, I even tried both of those. But in the first instance I forgot to enable delayed expansion, and in the second case I forgot the last %. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

```
CALL echo %%str:~%start%,%end%%%
```

in place of your version. No need for `enabledelayedexpansion`